# Chrome window.find aShowDialog argument doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

When I try to run following function on chrome.

```
window.find("text",false,false,true,false,false,true);
```

according to the documentation here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find
and here
http://help.dottoro.com/ljkjvqqo.php

This is supposed to show the search Dialog box.
I have tested. It works with firefox but not with chrome.
Any possible solutions?